# PreviewKeyDown event fired twice time

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview

What I am expecting is when I finish editing cell and click enter, the cursor would focus to a specified cell.

In my form, I expect the cursor focus on the cell column index 5, 2, 3 sequentially.
Later the next row columns index would be 5.

However the PreviewKeyDown event id processed twice.

So I pass the second step that I want and as a result get an error in the end.

This is the implementation I've tried so far:

```
void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtCell = e.Control as TextBox;
    if (txtCell != null) 
    {
        txtCell.PreviewKeyDown += new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(txtCell_PreviewKeyDown);
        txtCell.PreviewKeyDown += new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(txtCell_PreviewKeyDown);

        txtCell.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(txtCell_KeyDown);
        txtCell.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(txtCell_KeyDown);
    }
}

void txtCell_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        TextBox tCell = (TextBox)sender;

        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

void txtCell_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {
            int iColumn = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            int iRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

            if (iColumn == 5)
            {
                dataGridView1.Focus();
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[2, iRow];

                //-----I want to test the focus across the cell or not.
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = "123";
            }
            if (iColumn == 2)
            {
                dataGridView1.Focus();
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[3, iRow];

                //-----I want to test the focus across the cell or not.
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = "123";
            }
            if (iColumn == 3)
            {
                dataGridView1.Focus();
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[5, iRow + 1];

                //-----I want to test the focus across the cell or not.
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = "123";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this wpf? If so you need to mark the event as handled.

Comment: Yes, it's window form application.
Need what?
I'm just a beginner.
Can you explain me more.
Thank for your help.

Comment: Is this a winform or WPF ?

Comment: This is a winform.
But thank you.
I solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Nimesh.
I don't why too.
But I solved it like this......

```
public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing);
    }

    bool flag = false;

    void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtCell = e.Control as TextBox;
        if (txtCell != null) 
        {
            txtCell.PreviewKeyDown -= new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(txtCell_PreviewKeyDown);
            txtCell.PreviewKeyDown += new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(txtCell_PreviewKeyDown);

            txtCell.KeyDown -= new KeyEventHandler(txtCell_KeyDown);
            txtCell.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(txtCell_KeyDown);
        }
    }

    void txtCell_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            TextBox tCell = (TextBox)sender;

            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void txtCell_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tCell = (TextBox)sender;

        if (!flag)
        {
            flag = true;

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
            {
                //e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                int iColumn = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                int iRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

                if (iColumn == 5)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Focus();
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[2, iRow];
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = "123";
                    iColumn = 0;
                    iRow = 0;
                    flag = false;
                    return;
                }
                if (iColumn == 2)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Focus();
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[3, iRow];
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = "123";
                    iColumn = 0;
                    iRow = 0;
                    flag = false;
                    return;
                }
                if (iColumn == 3)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Focus();
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[5, iRow + 1];
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = "123";
                    iColumn = 0;
                    iRow = 0;
                    flag = false;
                    return;
                }
                flag = false;
                return;
            }
            flag = false;
            return;
        }
        flag = false;
        return;
    }

    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Focus();
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[5];
    }
```

Comment: e.Handled = true; is the crucial part

Answer (score 0):

Change following code. You are creating handler for twice and you should remove handler before adding new handler. it will remove already created handler if any.

```
void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtCell = e.Control as TextBox;
    if (txtCell != null) 
    {
        txtCell.PreviewKeyDown -= new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(txtCell_PreviewKeyDown);
        txtCell.PreviewKeyDown += new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(txtCell_PreviewKeyDown);

        txtCell.KeyDown -= new KeyEventHandler(txtCell_KeyDown);
        txtCell.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(txtCell_KeyDown);
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you know that your code executing that event twice? I mean are you debugging your code using F11/F10 key? place a line in that event `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());` and check in output window. Is your code print datetime twice when you press any key? and don't press any other key like alt+tab or ctrl+tab to switch window. use your mouse instead.

Comment: Yes, I use debug and F10.